# Trouble accessing the files in home directory

Tags: webserver, home-directory

I have a webserver (currently without a domain, since it's just for testing purposes at the moment) which runs on CentOS 7.1 x64. The server has Sentora preinstalled (with File Manager missing for some reason).

I have created an FTP account, connected to it via FileZilla, uploaded a file (index.php, with just phpinfo() in it). When I try to access the file or list the directory via (IP and username given are for illustrative purposes) `127.0.0.1/zadmin_user`, I get the standard 404. I have also tried `127.0.0.1/~zadmin_user`, and came back with a 404 as well.

What am I doing wrong and how can I access the uploaded file via the browser? Am I targeting the wrong path?

In case it's unclear what I'm asking, I want to be able to type (again, IP given for illustrative purposes, the real IP is different) `127.0.0.1\zadmin_user\index.php`, and have my browser access the file.

**EDIT**

Additional info

Server: Apache 2.4.6 / CentOS 7.1 x64

hosts file contents (IP in second row changed just in my post, not on server and in hosts file; same for myfictionalsite.net)

```
# Automatically generated by OnApp (3.0.7)
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.1.    sentora.myfictionalsite.net
127.0.0.1 sentora.myfictionalsite.net
127.0.0.1 autoreply.sentora.myfictionalsite.net
```

Permissions for /root are 550, and for var/www 755.

Comment: Sorry but your need to provide more information, the http server software your using e.g nginx, apache, the contents of your virtual host files and whether or not you have changed file and directory permissions of the home folder so that the web server process has rights to access those files.

Comment: @SimonHayter I've added the info which was missing from my original post.

Comment: There still isn't enough information to answer your question.   What entries are in the error_log?   What is your virtual host configuration?